# What is point of transformation if the effects does not change?

Tags: statistical-significance, anova, mixed-model, data-transformation, normality-assumption

with a question related to transformation.

I have done a linear mixed model using the formula

```
trait ~ Iso + Host + Iso:Host + Replication + Iso:Replication + Host:Replication
```

It is a greenhouse experiment with three chambers treated as three replications. The environmental condition is different in each chamber due to some malfunction. Although, I set the replication and associated interaction as random effects.

In the first step, I have used non-transformed values, and my residuals does not look normal. Then, I did various transformations like log, box-cox, and finally selected rank based inverse normal transformation as this fits the assumptions.

But the problem is, it does not matter if I use transformed or non-transformed data, the effect of each variable in the ANOVA remain significant. Although the F-value, AIC value improved. But the significance of each variable remain unchanged. It is not like with non-transformed they were NS and after transformation they became significant.

So, should I still stick to transformation of data or go back to original data?
Moreover, if I use a transformed dataset for ANOVA, do I have to keep using the transformed data for subsequent analyses? Or can I use original data for subsequent analyses?

Comment: Re the title: ordinarily we make a sharp distinction between *significance* (the ability to detect something) and *effects* (the quantities that are detected).  Appreciating this distinction might help you answer this question yourself.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Also, it does not answer all of my questions.